# Find the nearest number of specific number which has specific digit (7)

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, digit

Well, I have to write a program to find the NEAREST number of given number N which has exactly "K" 7s.

For example, if input is:

```
N K
1773 3
```

Output:

```
1777
```

Oh, one more thing is that N can be 100 000 000 000 000 maximum, will long long be enough to handle this?

My code so far which is not working :(

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned long long a, i;
    int b, num=0, dig, tmp;
    cin>>a>>b;
    i=a+1;
    do
    {
        num=0;
        tmp=i;
        while (tmp>0)
        {
            dig=tmp%10;
            tmp=tmp/10;
            if (dig==7)
            num++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    while(num<b);
    cout<<i-1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Huh, two homeworks within half an hour?

Comment: @H2CO3: I'd say someone trying to cheat in a TopCoder competition

Comment: Not homework, I don't study programming @ school.

Comment: I don't know what TopCoder competition is either, I am doing challenges from an eBook and usually challenges on spoj.com.

Comment: "not working" is not specific enough. What have you already tried? Help us help you.

Comment: My code is in the first post as you can see.... it appears my problem is in the loops.

Comment: If the input is N=83, K=1, is the right answer 79 or 87? Or do you want to see both?

Comment: Inculdes both.. but I already managed to solve it, except the long long part doesn't really seem to be reaching that limit.

Comment: I have updated the post with fully working version, EXCEPT it's taking TOOOOOOO long to calculate for big numbers. Any help how to prevent that?

Comment: If the input is N=82, K=1, your description clearly states your desired output is 79, but your program outputs 87. Unless your description is wrong, you don't have a working version yet, so the version you have now isn't what you should be making faster. For my earlier question, you replied "both", but your program does not output both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not a programming problem but a math problem.

Let `m = 1+E(log10(N))`, ie the number of digits in the decimal writing of `N` (it will be probably faster to compute it by counting digits than using a logarithm).

Let `mK` be the number of `7` in `N`.

Let `N'` be the output number.

I see 4 cases:

- `K >= m` : then `N' = 7..7` (`K` digits).
- `K == mK` : then `N' = N`.
- `K > mK and K < m` : then you replace all non-`7` digits with `7`, starting from the least significant digits. Ex: `N = 1 357 975 , K = 4 => N' = 1 357 777`. Warning : there is a special case, if you have a `8`, ex: `N = 80, N' = 79`. You can do this case by using a common prefix, and then generating an all `7` suffix (special case: remove one more from the prefix and add `7 9 7 7 ... 7`). See `special case` in the code.
- `K < mK` : there are two possible numbers.

  Lets decompose `N`: `N = a1 a2 ... ap 7 b1 b2 ... bq`, where

  - `a1 ... ap` are `p` numbers in `[0..9]` and
  - `b1 ... bq` are `q` numbers in `[0..9] \ {7}`

  Let `A = a1 ... ap 6 9 ... 9` and `B = a1 ... ap 8 0 ... 0` (`q` digits after the `6`or  the `8`). Then, `N' = closestToN(A,B)`. If both numbers are equally close, the choice is up to you.

*Sorry for the bad math formatting.*
The code can now be more easy to write. [Here is my implementation](http://ideone.com/8eevEa):

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long getClosestWith7(unsigned long long n, unsigned int k)
{
    // Count number of digits
    unsigned long long tmp = n;
    unsigned int m = 0, mK = 0;
    while(tmp > 0)
    {
        if(tmp % 10 == 7) mK++;
        tmp /= 10;
        m++;
    }

    // Distinct cases
    if(k == mK && n != 0)
        return n;
    else if(k >= m || n == 0) // implicit: k != mK
    {
        unsigned long long r = 0;
        while(k > 0)
        {
            r = 10 * r + 7;
            k--;
        }
        return r;
    }
    else if(k > mK) // implicit: k != mK, k < m
    {
        unsigned long long r = n;
        unsigned long long s = 0;
        m = 0;
        while(mK < k)
        {
            if(r % 10 != 7) mK++;
            r /= 10;
            m++;
        }
        if(r % 10 == 8) // special case
            s = 79 + 100 * (r / 10);
        while(m > 0)
        {
            r = 10 * r + 7;
            if(s != 0 && m > 1) // special case
                s = 10 * s + 7;
            m--;
        }
        return (r < n && n - r < n - s) || (r >= n && r - n < n - s) ? r : s;
    }
    else // implicit : k < mK
    {
        // Generate a and b
        unsigned long long a = n;
        unsigned long long b = 0;
        m = 0;
        while(mK > k)
        {
            if(a % 10 == 7) mK--;
            a /= 10;
            m++;
        }
        b = 10 * a + 8;
        a = 10 * a + 6;
        m--;
        while(m > 0)
        {
            a = 10 * a + 9;
            b = 10 * b + 0;
            m--;
        }

        // Compare (return lowest if equal)
        return n - a <= b - n ? a : b;
    }
}

#define CLOSEST7( N , K ) \
    std::cout << "N = " << N << ", K = " << K << " => N' = " << getClosestWith7(N,K) << "\n"

int main()
{
    CLOSEST7(1773,3);
    CLOSEST7(83,1);
    CLOSEST7(17273,3);
    CLOSEST7(1273679750,6);
    CLOSEST7(1773,1);
    CLOSEST7(83,5);
    CLOSEST7(0,2);
    CLOSEST7(0,0);
}
```

For your question about `long long`: it depends on the compiler. Often, the size of this type is 64 bits, so you can store number from 0 to 2^64 - 1 (unsigned), which is 18 446 744 073 709 551 615, so it should be ok for your data range on most implementations.

Comment: Compiler: g++ 4.7.1, long long can't seem to reach that number.. any ideas?

Comment: Actually, it does reach it, my problem was time exceeded... please see my first post with my version, if you can, what could be the problem causing that? And how do I prevent?

Comment: As Dukeling said, you're counting numbers one by one. It is way too long... Also, use `unsigned long long int` for max number ([I got it working with gcc 4.7.2](http://ideone.com/FzLqgM), probably in 32 bits). It seems it can vary on whether you're compiling on 32 or 64 bits. Here you don't need negative integers, so use unsigned.

Comment: @JohnSmith I added an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Some problems:

- `ans=i` records some `i` after you've divided it a few times, you need to record the original `i`
- You only loop in 1 direction, you need to check in both directions at the same time
- Looping through all numbers is fundamentally too slow

  - If the number is 100 000 000 000 000 and k = 14, you'd need to check 22 222 222 222 223 (100 000 000 000 000-77 777 777 777 777) numbers, which is not viable

Side note - [the maximum for long long is 9223372036854775807](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).

Here is some pseudo-code which should work:

```
num = number of 7s in input
if (num == k)
  print input
if (num < k)
  a = input with (k-num) non-7 digits from least significant digit set to 7
    let x = last position set
  b = substring(input, 1, position)
  c = b + 1
  d = b - 1
  ba = concat(b, substring(a, position, end))
  ca = concat(c, substring(a, position, end))
  da = concat(d, substring(a, position, end))
  if (abs(input - ba) <= abs(input - ca) &&
      abs(input - ba) <= abs(input - da))
    print b
  else
  if (abs(input - ca) <= abs(input - ba) &&
      abs(input - ca) <= abs(input - da))
    print c
  else
    print d
if (num > k)
  x = (k-num)th 7 from least significant digit
  a = input with x set to 6 and all less significant digits to 9
  b = input with x set to 8 and all less significant digits to 0
  if (input - a > b - input)
    print b
  else
    print a
```

Comment: I will attempt your version soon, however, do you mind checking MY version in first post and tell me why is my program exceeding time limits for big numbers?

Comment: @JohnSmith See the 3rd point in my answer. The approach is fundamentally too slow. Checking 22 222 222 222 223 numbers will take waaaay too long. Also, `while(num<b)` should be `while(num!=b)`, but this will only make the program take longer. Also note the 2nd point in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this algorithm?

1. Convert the number into a string.
2. Count the number of 7s in it.
3. If it has less 7s than K, change the numbers from the right-most to left into 7s one-by-one until K is reached, then go to step 5.
4. If it has more 7s than K, change the numbers from the right-most to left into 6s one-by-one only if they are 7, until K is reached, then go to step 5.
5. Convert it back into an integer.

`long long` is usable according to Dukeling's answer.